# Visual Studio 2010 e Conexão com Banco Access

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-access

Meu Visual Studio 2010 (10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel), está estourando a seguinte mensagem de erro quando tento criar uma conexão com um banco de dados Access (Office 2010):

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Já atualizei os componentes de acesso a dados (MDAC 2.8 SP1) e registrei manualmente os arquivos MSJET40.dll tanto da pasta SysWOW64 quanto da pasta System32 e mesmo após várias tentativas o problema persiste.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que esse problema ocorre nas versões x64. 
Tente instalar o [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Mais detalhes sobre o problema [aqui](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb).

Comment: Tiago. A solução passada funcionou?

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, Maia!

O segundo link redireciona para um artigo em inglês que sugere o download e instalação do componente "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components" que é para Office 2007, mas por algum motivo misterioso, funcionou perfeitamente em minha máquina, que tem o Office 2010 64-bit. Vai entender... =P

De qualquer maneira, muito obrigado mesmo!